# Blender 2.79 - Where/How to see which bone connected to which vertices group?

Tags: bones

Is there a way to see which vertex groups name a bone is connected to?

Comment: A bone always affects vertex groups with the exact same name that the bone has.

Comment: I have tested that I can change the name of a vertex group. But the bone name remain the same. In that case how to recognize it?

Comment: If you change the name of a vertex group without changing the name of the bone, then that bone no longer affects the mesh whatsoever.  It is not connected in any way.